# Automated Data Expansion based on Start and End Dates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have data spanning from Column A to Column K in a Google Sheets spreadsheet. Column E contains the Start Date, and Column F contains the End Date. Now, I want to expand the data based on the number of days between the Start Date and End Date, while keeping the remaining values unchanged.

For example, if the Start Date is 01-Jan-2023 and the End Date is 05-Jan-2023, the desired outcome is to generate 5 rows with each row containing the corresponding Start Date and End Date. The other columns should retain the data from the original rows.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
    ROW(E2:E) <= (F2:F - E2:E + 1),
    SPLIT(REPT(TEXT(E2:E, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & CHAR(9) & TEXT(E2:E, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & CHAR(10), F2:F - E2:E + 1), CHAR(10)),
    ""
  )
)
```

Input

| Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- |
| 01-Jan-2023 | 05-Jan-2023 |

Output

| Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- |
| 01-Jan-2023 | 01-Jan-2023 |
| 02-Jan-2023 | 02-Jan-2023 |
| 03-Jan-2023 | 03-Jan-2023 |
| 04-Jan-2023 | 04-Jan-2023 |
| 05-Jan-2023 | 05-Jan-2023 |

Pleasew find the attached [Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gxjXvNCiAOCAenPHBfHbiBYsvqkO1VEcmRW8i9YExzA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here's [one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gxjXvNCiAOCAenPHBfHbiBYsvqkO1VEcmRW8i9YExzA/edit#gid=1143490349) you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,map(Input!E2:E,Input!F2:F,lambda(e,f,if(e="",,sequence(1,days(f,e-1),e,1)))), Λ,byrow(Σ,lambda(z,counta(z))),
 z,hstack(reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(let(a,Input!A2:A,index(match(,0/(a<>""))))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,iferror(index(if(sequence(index(Λ,c)),index(Input!A2:G,c))),tocol(,1))))),tocol(Σ,1)),
   choosecols(z,1,2,3,4,8,8,7))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for being late. Thank you very much its great!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
=LET(data,Input!A1:XLOOKUP("?*",Input!G:G,Input!G:G,,2,-1),
     header,INDEX(data,1),
     BYCOL(IFNA(
       REDUCE(header,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)-1),
         LAMBDA(_data,i,
           LET(employee_code,INDEX(data,i+1,1),
               employee,INDEX(data,i+1,2),
               team,INDEX(data,i+1,3),
               week,INDEX(data,i+1,4),
               start_date,INDEX(data,i+1,5),
               end_date,INDEX(data,i+1,6),
               leave_type,INDEX(data,i+1,7),
               dates,SEQUENCE(end_date-start_date+1,1,start_date),
               VSTACK(
               _data,
               HSTACK(employee_code,employee,team,week,dates,dates,leave_type)))))),
     LAMBDA(data,SCAN(,data,LAMBDA(_data,cur,IF(cur="",_data,cur))))))
```

Comment: Sorry for being late. Thank you @ztiaa for the answer.